# what are override methods and how do they work?

Tags: object, methods, overriding, instance, equals

I was doing some comp sci homework, and realized I had forgotten the concept of overriding   a method. I have to override the equals method, in this code:

```
public boolean equals( Object b ) 
{ 
  if ( ! (b instanceof Employee) ) 
    return false;
```

So, I have to add in code that overrides a method, but I forgot what override means. Could someone explain it as a concept a little better? How does it apply to this code?

Answer (score 0):

When you are overriding, you are basically taking the function that is it is using by the class that implements it, and making it better. For example, when using the paintComponent method, you usually have the @override above it like:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    doDrawing(g);
}
```

notice that you have to call the super.paintComponent(g); inside the method. This is how the overriding is done, is by using the super implementation to start it, and then using your own code to increase the uniqueness about it.

hope that helps

Comment: does "super." refer to the whole method? I mean the outer one.

Comment: super is used as the "first implementer" it is taking what the Java developers already used in the paintComponent method, and using your code to make it work for how you need it.